# How to display the name of an uploaded file

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

I'm using this statement to try to echo the name of the file that is uploaded but it doesn't do anything:

```
echo $musicName = $_FILES["music"]["name"];
```

This is the html form:

```
<form action="UploadMusic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File:
    <input type="file" name="music"/> <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try dumping files array with `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what's inside?

Comment: It's saying music is an array for some reason

Comment: `code{ ["music"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "JobAd.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php1tXOpA" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(543033) } } `                              (I uploaded a image just because I don't have any mp3 songs on my computer right now)

Answer (score 0):

It worked to declare the variable first, and then echo it out. Someone who answered this question suggested that but then deleted the answer for some reason.

Comment: He removed the answer because `echo $someVar = 'some value';` works fine. The issue must be somewhere else.